# Kotlin mockito: Stubbing mock with ArgumentMatchers makes stubbing parameters as null

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I am working on a kotlin spring application that makes use of Thymeleaf library for rendering templates from a file. Our application has to render the file using variables defined in a context, so this has to be mocked in an unit test.

Since the `thymeleaf`'s engine classes have final methods, we have to make use of the interface that has the definition of the method we are using, which in this case is `process`.. So in the spring controller we are injecting `ITemplateEngine` from `thymeleaf` and we are creating a mock of that same interface in the unit test suite

```
// Example class to test
@Controller
class MyController(
    private val templateEngine: ITemplateEngine
): ControllerAPI {
    override fun getTemplateContent(): ResponseEntity<String> {
        val context = Context()

        context.setVariables(
            mapOf(
                Pair("scriptUrl", "localhost/assets/widget.min.js")
            )
        )

        val content = templateEngine.process("scripts/controller.js", context)

        return ResponseEntity<String>(content, HttpStatus.OK)
    }
}
```

So for this example, the unit test is defined as follows:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
internal class ControllerTest {
    lateinit var controller: MyController

    @Mock
    lateinit var templateEngine: ITemplateEngine


    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        controller = MyController(templateEngine)
    }

    @Test
    fun getTemplateContent() {
        val context = Context()

        context.setVariables(
            mapOf(
                Pair("scriptUrl", "localhost/assets/widget.min.js")
            )
        )

        `when`(templateEngine.process(eq("scripts/controller.js"), refEq(context)))
            .thenReturn("foobar")

        val result = controller.getTemplateContent()
    }
}
```

When running this test, i get the following error:

```
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'process' method:
    templateEngine.process(
    "scripts/controller.js",
    org.thymeleaf.context.Context@76cf841
);
    -> at com.development.kotlin.spike.application.spike.gateway.web.MyController.getTemplateContent(MyController.kt:6)
  - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. templateEngine.process(null, null)
```

At this point i'm scratching my head trying to understand why for some reason the stubbing has the parameters as null, i have tried not using `ArgumentMatchers` but the test fails due to the mock not being called since the context created in the test is a different instance than the one created by the mock.

I might be missing something, but i'd like to understand why the arguments are null, and if there's a good practice when it comes to mocking then i'd like to know.

Comment: I don't know anything about kotlin, but in the Java version of Mockito, when you stub a method, you have to say what you want to have happen when the method is called, or at the very least, what should be returned.  You've got a `when` call, without any  `thenReturn` or `thenAnswer` on the result, and that's always an error.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem sorry, i didn't notice it wasn't there.. but i added it just to make it clear. The way how mockito is used in kotlin is the same way as in java, just with a few differences due to how kotlin syntax works, like `when` is a keyword in kotlin so you have to literally specify that you are calling a method instead of a keyword by surrounding it with tildes. The error still appears though, so the problem is coming from `ArgumentMatchers` returning null, i've done some debugging and found that out

Comment: Argument matchers are supposed to return null at stubbing time (or the right kind of zero/false if they're matching a primitive).  But the matchers themselves are stored so they can be used when the stubbed method is called.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Sorry for the late reply.. i understand that they are supposed to return null and the stubbing is stored somewhere, but do you have an idea why i'm getting the error mentioned in the post?

Comment: I'm trying to work out what's going on with your parentheses.  You seem to be passing two arguments to `eq`, and I'm surprised that this compiles.  Also, is there a reason why you didn't use the backticks on `eq` or `refEq`?  (Sorry, maybe I shouldn't try to answer when I don't know kotlin)

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I didn't use backticks because there are no keywords for `eq` or `refEq`.. i am only using them in `when` because that is a keyword in kotlin which works kinda the same as `switch`.. and so to reference the `when` from mockito's instead of kotlin's then backticks are used for literal reference.. this is also because i am importing all the mockito methods in the import clause

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  Anyway, your parentheses still look wrong.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I've noticed that, it must have been a copy error so i fixed it and made sure that the syntax is similar to the source code